# An incorrect privilege appears as to be earned on Android and iOS apps

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, ios-app

I've just gained 125 points on StackOverflow and earned the "vote down" privilege. This appears correctly on the desktop site, under the Recent Achievements icon in the toolbar. However, on my mobile apps, both Android and iOS, the new privilege that appears under that icon is the "create tag synonyms".
When I click on that notification, the following happens:

- Under Android, the app crashes.
- Under iOS, a blank page appears.

The app version is as follows:

- 1.0.48 for Android.
- 1.0.1 for iOS.

Comment: Same issue as the dupe, needs to be re-deployed for the mobile bits, which I will be doing now.